# Rollback all migrations with ragtime

Tags: clojure, database-migration, rollback

I'm dealing with some code that assumed that the `rollback` function below would roll back all migrations. However, it only seems to roll back the latest migration.

```
(defn create-migrator
  [spec]
  {:datastore  (ragtime.jdbc/sql-database spec)
   :migrations (ragtime.jdbc/load-resources "migrations")})

(defn rollback
  [env]
  (-> (create-db-spec env)
      (create-migrator)
      (ragtime.repl/rollback)))
```

How can I alter `rollback` to roll back all migrations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ragtime [`rollback` function](http://weavejester.github.io/ragtime/ragtime.repl.html#var-rollback) accepts multiple options. Among them there is number of migrations to rollback or ID of migration you want to rollback to (`amount-or-id`).

As `ragtime.jdbc/load-resources` returns a seq of all migrations sorted by their names (and by convention they will be sorted by their order of application) you can query the first one and get its ID:

```
(-> (ragtime.jdbc/load-resources "migrations")
    (first)
    (:id))
```

If your database is at the latest migrations I guess using `count` of your migrations seq as `amount` should also work.

---

For the given example:

```
(defn rollback-all
  [env]
  (let [spec (create-db-spec env)
        migrator (create-migrator spec)
        count-migrations (-> migrator :migrations count)]
    (ragtime.repl/rollback migrator count-migrations)))
```

Comment: So... using this information, how do I dynamically roll back all of the migrations? Is there a way to query how many migrations there are? Or is there a "migration id" that represents the beginning of time?

Comment: Enhanced the answer with relevant info about migration ID.